# PHP PCRE2 no more memory

Tags: php, wordpress, out-of-memory, pcre, jit

I'm running a CentOS 7 on a physical server, and I found a warning about JIT out of memory. The problem appears on a WordPress 4.9.8 installation when migrating to PHP 7.3RC2. PHP 7.3 update to the PCRE2 version of the library.

Log saves lots of warnings, in every preg_match and preg_replace, and it is always the same: `JIT compilation failed. No more memory.`
As far as I could debug the function results were correct.
If I try to debug a simple preg_match call on a small PHP file, the problem does not appear, but on another big PHP site like phpMyAdmin, it happens again.

I couldn't find anything on the web, and I think it is a very particular problem of either the implementation of the PCRE2 library in the Remi Repo or the PHP7.3RC2 + PCRE2 combination because I can't reproduce the problem in a VM.

**Update 1**: I couldn't find a good how-to guide to increase the stack size of the library.

**Update 2**: physical server has SELinux enabled. I will investigate this way. For the time being, the PHP version was downgraded to 7.2.

If somebody has the same problem or any idea, please let me know.

Comment: i think you need to increase the PCRE JIT stack size limit

Comment: this could be of help https://externals.io/message/87245 its an old article but has the same issue with the same PHP version

Comment: By default pcre.jit=0 (in package from my repo) as it raise SElinux issues.

Comment: I can reproduce this building PHP from source on my Mac. I can confirm that disabling `pcre.jit` avoids these errors. What that does to performance I'll be testing